# Why are large cardinal axioms actually axioms?

Tags: soft-question, set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

A cardinal is an isomorphism class in ZFC, or a representative of one.

I'm not asking what the significant uses of *large cardinals* are, or why we would want to find them or construct them; I'm asking why are they axioms; Hilbert spaces are useful, and there are axioms that define them, but they're not at the (set-theoretical) foundational level. Can we say that large cardinal axioms are not foundational?

My understanding is that they are *in fact* foundational (going by wikipedia); is this correct?

Further, (again going by wikipedia) large cardinals *axioms* are necessary when we can't show that certain cardinals exist; and I understand by this that some condition is given that picks out a cardinality. But we can't show that we can construct that set by the operations of set-theory starting from any previously constructed cardinals (the first one is a given by the axiom of infinity).

Is this right?

I apologise for the lack of precision in this question - it was going to be a question on Philosophy.SE; but then I thought this site would be better.

Comment: The second sentence certainly does not mean anything. It is not what large cardinals are for. The answer to the question "Is this right?" is no, definitely. There are uses: Combinatorially they have rich properties. Metamathematically, they allow us to calibrate the consistency strength of theories extending $\mathsf{ZF}$. Mathematically, they provide us with a coherent picture of the theory of the reals beyond that given by the standard axioms, a theory that is complete in a profound technical sense.

Comment: @caicedo: sure, they're useful; I'm not disputing that; I'm asking why are they *axioms*; Hilbert spaces are useful, and there are axioms that define them, but they're not at foundational level. Are you saying that large cardinal axioms are not foundational?

Comment: @Caicedo: I've rephrased the question heading to make this more explicit.

Comment: The new title is completely different. Still, the body of the question talks of something else. If you edit your first comment into the question, that would go a long way into clarifying what you are after.

Comment: @Caicedo: done.

Comment: Thanks, I think the current version is much better. I made a tiny edit to increase clarity.

Comment: But the Hilbert space axioms _are_ axioms, right?  It seems like your question is really "why found mathematics on [$\mathsf{ZFC}$ plus] large cardinal axioms?" rather than "why are large cardinal axioms actually axioms?"  This is a reasonable question, to which deep answers are possible.  I'm not sure I understand the alternative you have in mind, though.  The Hilbert space axioms can be proved to have a model in $\mathsf{ZFC}$, so it would be redundant to add them to $\mathsf{ZFC}$. Large cardinal axioms cannot, more or less by definition.

Comment: @Wilson: sure, and so are the Peano Axioms; but can't one write the them in terms of the ZFC ones? If one can do that, then isn't it a legitimate supposition that one can do the same with the Hilbert Space axioms? I'm thinking perhaps purely syntactically, rather than (or also) semantically which possibally is giving rise to my confusion. I didn't have an alternative in mind!

Answer (score 3):

A Hilbert space is a set with some structure. It's not hard to show in ZFC that Hilbert spaces exist, but if we wanted to we could consider some extremely weak theory $T\subset ZFC$ which can't prove e.g. that the reals form a set; then the statement "There is a Hilbert space" might not be provable in $T$, and would - if we wanted to use Hilbert spaces - need to be added as an axiom.

Large cardinal axioms are this, but in a context that's less silly. A large cardinal is a set with some properties (for various reasons, I hesitate to say "structure" here); for instance, a measurable is a cardinal which carries a countably complete ultrafilter (or many other equivalent formulations). The large cardinal *axiom* for a measurable is the statement,

> There exists a measurable cardinal.

This is *not* the same sort of thing as the defining "axioms" for a Hilbert space; those are analogous instead to the statement "$\kappa$ is measurable iff $\kappa$ is a cardinal and there is a countably complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$ which is nonprincipal;" both are really *definitions*. But we can make sense of a definition without knowing that something satisfying it exists! So this is the sense in which an axiom is required: without the large cardinal axioms, we can't tell that the large cardinal *definitions* apply to anything.